# SQL find rows in table based on search results in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm looking for a way to search a table values from the results of a query on another table :

```
SELECT entry_id FROM FEEDENTRYSTATUSES WHERE starred > 0 ;
+----------+
| entry_id |
+----------+
|     1036 |
|     1059 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT url from FEEDENTRIES WHERE id = 1036 ;
+---------------------+
| url                 |
+---------------------+
| https://google.com/ |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I can get a list of IDs from the FEEDENTRYSTATUSES table.
I can retrieve value from second table manually by giving the value **1036**.
But I would like to search in table FEEDENTRIES from values returned by first SELECT.

Is here a way to do so ?
Any help very much appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Go for `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IN` operator and subquery to achieve that:

```
SELECT url from FEEDENTRIES 
WHERE id IN (SELECT entry_id FROM FEEDENTRYSTATUSES WHERE starred > 0);
```

Or join the tables and filter the data that you need:

```
SELECT fe.url from FEEDENTRIES fe
    INNER JOIN FEEDENTRYSTATUSES fes ON fe.id = fes.entry_id
WHERE fes.starred > 0;
```